# Why does Elixir have so many similar list types in the standard library?

Tags: list, types, elixir

I'm doing the [Elixir koans](http://elixirkoans.io/), and already I've worked through something like five different listy data types:

- List
- Char list
- Word list
- Tuple
- Keyword list
- Map
- MapSet
- Struct

Some of these I buy, but all of them at the same time? Does anyone actually use all of these lists for strictly separated purposes?

Comment: please clarify what you mean by Word List

Comment: Word list is what is generated when you use the `w` and `W` sigils on a string.

Comment: Thanks, http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#word-lists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer is: yes.

Long answer is:

- Lists - are a basic data structure you use everywhere. Lists are ordered and allow duplicates. The main use case is: homogenous varied-length collections
- Charlists - where Elixir uses strings (based on binaries), Erlang usually uses charlists (lists of integer codepoints). It's mainly a compatibility interface;
- Word lists - I've never heard of those;
- Tuples - are another basic data structure you use everywhere. The main use case is: heterogenous fixed-length collections;
- Keyword lists - are very common, mainly used for options. It's a simple abstraction on top of lists and tuples (a list of two-element tuples). Allow for duplicate keys and maintain order of keys, since they are ordered pattern-matching is very impractical.
- Maps - are common too. Allow for easy pattern matching on keys, but do not allow duplicate keys and are not ordered.
- MapSet - sets are a basic data structure - an unordered, unique collection of elements.
- Structs - are the main mechanism for polymorphism in Elixir (through protocols), allow creating more rigid structures with keyset enforced at compile-time.

With functional programming choosing the right data structure to represent your data is often half of the issue, that's why you get so many different structures, with different characteristics. Each one has it's use-cases and is useful in different ways.

Answer (score 3):

@michalmuskala provided here great answer, maybe I just extend it a bit.

- Lists are the workhorse in Elixir. There's a plenty of issues that you will solve with lists. Lists are not arrays, where random access is the best way to get values, instead lists in Elixir are **linked data structures** and you traverse them by splitting into head and tail (if you know LISP, Prolog or Erlang, you'd will just like in home).
- Charlists are just lists, but narrowed to lists of integers.
- Tuples - usually they contain two to four elements. There are common way to pass additional data, but still send one parameter. Common behaviours like **GenServer** etc. uses them as an expected reply.
- Keyword lists are list of tuples and you can use them when you need to store for one key more than one value. This is syntantic sugar.
  Instead of `a = [{:name, "Patryk"}]` you can have `a = [name: "Patryk"]` and access it with `a[:name]`.
- Maps are associative arrays, hashes, dicts etc. One key holds one value and keys are unique.
- Set  - think about mathematicians sets. Unordered collection of unique values.
- Struct - as @michalmuskala wrote they are used in protocols and they are checked by the compiler. Actually they're maps defined for module.

Answer (score 2):

The answers are to be read from the bottom to the top :)

@michalmuskala provided here great answer, @patnowak extended it perfectly. I am here to mostly answer to the question “Does anyone actually use all of these lists for strictly separated purposes?“

Elixir (as well as Erlang) is all **about pattern matching**. Having different types of lists makes it easy to narrow the pattern matching in each particular case:

- `List` is used mostly in *recursion*; Erlang has no loops, instead one does recursive calls. It’s highly optimized when used properly (tail-recursion.) Usually matches as `[head | tail]`.
- `charlist` is used in “string” pattern matching, whatever it means. Check for “the first letter of his name is ‘A’” in Erlang would be done with pattern match against `[?A | rest] = "Aleksei" |> List.Chars.to_charlist`
- `Tuple` is used in pattern matching of different instances of the more-or-less same entity. Fail/Success would be returned as tuples `{:ok, result}` and `{:error, message}` respectively and pattern matched afterwards. `GenServer` simplifies handling of different messages that way as well.
- `Map` is to be pattern matched as `%{name: "Aleksei"} = generic_input` to immediately extract the `name`. `Keyword`s are more or less the same.

etc.